Getting this issue of no module named pip and says not likely an error with pip
My Django project was working fine...For some reason I delete my virtual environment. I created new virtual environment and activate it. But now, I am getting this issue all of a sudden...My python version 3.12.3 ... I changed it to Python 3.11.7 but it didnt solve...This error is for python 3.12.3 version..I also installed wheel package, but it didnt work. I also installed pip install zombie-imp What is the issue?
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\kvwsmb\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>          main()
        File "E:\kvwsmb\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main    
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\kvwsmb\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Saroj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v7wrdfbd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Saroj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v7wrdfbd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Saroj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v7wrdfbd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Saroj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v7wrdfbd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
(myvenv) PS E:\kvwsmb> 

My requirements.txt is as follows:
pytz==2021.1  # https://github.com/stub42/pytz
python-slugify==4.0.1  # https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify
argon2-cffi==20.1.0  # https://github.com/hynek/argon2_cffi
redis==3.5.3  # https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py
hiredis==1.1.0  # https://github.com/redis/hiredis-py

tablib
# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
django==3.1.7  # pyup: < 3.2  # https://www.djangoproject.com/
django-environ==0.4.5  # https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ
django-model-utils==4.1.1  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils
django-allauth==0.44.0  # https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
django-crispy-forms==1.11.1  # https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms
django-redis==4.12.1  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis
django-cors-headers
django-rest-passwordreset
pillow
gunicorn
Collectfast
dj-database-url
django-autoslug
django-rest-knox
django-import-export
Werkzeug==1.0.1 # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug
ipdb==0.13.5  # https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb
# https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2

# Testing
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mypy==0.812  # https://github.com/python/mypy
django-stubs==1.7.0  # https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs
pytest==6.2.2  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
pytest-sugar==0.9.4  # https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar

# Documentation
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sphinx==3.5.1  # https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
sphinx-autobuild==2020.9.1 # https://github.com/GaretJax/sphinx-autobuild

# Code quality
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flake8==3.8.4  # https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
flake8-isort==4.0.0  # https://github.com/gforcada/flake8-isort
coverage==5.5  # https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy
black==20.8b1  # https://github.com/ambv/black
pylint-django==2.4.2  # https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django
pre-commit==2.10.1  # https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit

# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
factory-boy==3.2.0  # https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy

django-debug-toolbar==3.2  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar
django-extensions==3.1.1  # https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
django-coverage-plugin==1.8.0  # https://github.com/nedbat/django_coverage_plugin
pytest-django==4.1.0  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django
whitenoise
djangorestframework
django-filter
django-tables2
drf-yasg
django-filter
# typed-ast==1.4.3

